Non-Classifiable Countable Math Objects
I was studying the classification of finite simple groups when I came up with this problem.
Are there countable math objects that cannot be fully classified? Let the set be $A$, that is:
1.Exists a definition that can determine whether some object $a\in A$.
2.We define a generator of $A$ as: A finitely long algorithm (that does not have to end in finite steps), which generates elements of $A$, s.t. either (1) it generates a total of finite elements in finite time; (2) $\forall N>0$, it can generate $N$ elements in polynomial time w.r.t.$N$.
3.If an element of $A$ shall be generated by a given generator in finite time, we say it is generated by that generator.
4.It is impossible to generate all elements of $A$ with any finite number of generators.
5.$A$ has countable elements in total, and there exists at least one generator of A.

Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_and_productive_sets

I don't understand what it means to say "it generates a total of finite elements".  Please clarify your definition of "generator".  Also, it seems your notion of "generator" doesn't require that all elements of A be generated.  For instance, an algorithm that only enumerates an infinite subset of A would still count as a "generator" under your definition.  Is that really the intention?  If so, that is a rather weird definition.  Also, the use of "polynomial time" is normally irrelevant to classification and enumeration.

I suggest learning about recursively enumerable languages and recursive languages.  Any language that is not recursively enumerable is a good candidate for qualifying.
For instance, consider the set of all Turing machines that do not halt on the empty input.  This is not recursively enumerable (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52503/755), so there is no algorithm to generate all of its members (and no finite set of algorithms that can, together, generate all of it).  However, there is a clearly specified definition of this set.
I think another example is the complement of the Entscheidungsproblem set.  Specifically, consider the set of all statements in first-order logic that cannot be proven using the rules of logic.  This set is not recursively enumerable (but is countable), so I believe it too is a good candidate for what you are looking for.
I don't find your definitions very clear, and I'm not sure that they are the right way to formalize what you actually care about, so I find it hard to mathematically verify whether these examples meet your requirements, but I suspect they satisfy the spirit of what you are going for.

give me a while to go through these and see whether I shall modify the question...
